# Merging two Javascript objects where each key contains multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I am currently in the process of learning JavaScript and had a quick question on a project i am working on. Currently If i want to merge a few Objects, add the values together if the keys match or append the parent obj if a key is not already existing, i can do the following:

```
var test1 = {
    a: 12,
    b: 8,
    c: 17
};

var test2 = {
    a: 22,
    b: 8,
    c: 9
};

var test3 = {
    a: 33,
    b: 23,
    c: 1,
    d: 2,
    e: 9
};

function sumObjectsByKey(...objs) {
    return objs.reduce((a, b) => {
        for (let k in b) {
            if (b.hasOwnProperty(k))
                a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + b[k]
        }
        return a;
    }, {});
    console.log("endresult" + " " + sumObjectsByKey(test1, test2, test3));
```

This seems to work just fine when there is just ONE value. ex: a: 22

So this is where my issue comes in. What if the objects look like this:

```
var test1 = {
testSystem: {crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22"}
testSystem1: {crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22"}
testSystem2: {crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22"}
testSystem3: {crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22"}
};

var test2 = {
testSystem: {crit: "19", high: "305", med: "21", low: "212"}
4testSystem1: {crit: "111", high: "10", med: "31", low: "62"}
testSystem2: {crit: "21", high: "3", med: "11", low: "232"}
testSystem4: {crit: "13", high: "40", med: "15", low: "22"}
testSystem7: {crit: "21", high: "3", med: "112", low: "32"}
};

var test3 = {
testSystem5: {crit: "1", high: "0", med: "122", low: "122"}
testSystem2: {crit: "2", high: "6", med: "1", low: "222"}
testSystem3: {crit: "6", high: "0", med: "12", low: "212"}
testSystem4: {crit: "4", high: "8", med: "11", low: "2"}
};
```

how can i modify the above code to iterate through to do the same as above? Any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Basically test2 and test3 would append test1 if a key does not already exist otherwise sum up the corresponding values. So for example if each var has a "testSystem2" you would add the crit,high,med,low values together. If there is no matching "testsystem" just append test1 obj with that the key and values.

Comment: Look into reducing an array of objects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the second object has a nested object, then call the function for the nested objects.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    Object.keys(b).forEach(k => {
        if (b[k] && typeof b[k] === 'object') return sum(a[k] = a[k] || {}, b[k]);
        a[k] = (+a[k] || 0) + +b[k];
    });
    return a;
}

var test1 = { testSystem: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" }, testSystem1: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" }, testSystem2: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" }, testSystem3: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" } },
    test2 = { testSystem: { crit: "19", high: "305", med: "21", low: "212" }, testSystem1: { crit: "111", high: "10", med: "31", low: "62" }, testSystem2: { crit: "21", high: "3", med: "11", low: "232" }, testSystem4: { crit: "13", high: "40", med: "15", low: "22" }, testSystem7: { crit: "21", high: "3", med: "112", low: "32" } },
    test3 = { testSystem5: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "122", low: "122" }, testSystem2: { crit: "2", high: "6", med: "1", low: "222" }, testSystem3: { crit: "6", high: "0", med: "12", low: "212" }, testSystem4: { crit: "4", high: "8", med: "11", low: "2" } };
  
console.log([test1, test2, test3].reduce(sum));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am curious though, why would I check if the second object has a nested object?

Comment: you like to mutate the first one, but only if the second has values to add, you need to check the properties of the second object.

Comment: On more question. What is the reason for the second plus sign in this: a[k] = (+a[k] || 0) + +b[k]; specificly I am talking about the '+ +b[k]'. Why is there two plus signs? Just curious and trying to understand.

Comment: it is an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) which converts a string to a number.